# How to check if confirmation is done or not yet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, confirmations

After sending Bitcoin to any address, how can I check if the transaction has at least one confirmation?

Should I poll the transaction repeatedly or is there any event when confirmation is  made.

Comment: What software, service, or API are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

In order to see if the transaction has confirmed, you can search for it in any indexed transaction database. This can include Bitcoin Core running in `-txindex` mode, or a block explorer such as [live.blockcypher.com](http://live.blockcypher.com) or [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info), for example. As soon as the transaction has been included in a block, it has 1 confirmation. If it is not found, or is still in the mempool, then it has either not propagated (failed validation checks), or has yet to be mined.